# How to convert this hex into an instruction?

Tags: ida

I have this little-endian thumb hex code: 44 79 (79 44) and I want to convert it into an instruction. How do I go about doing so? Compiling a program then decompiling it to get the instruction, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Online Disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) works well for small sequences of instructions.

[44 79](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/ZqHUIva4/0)

```
.data:00000000  7944    ldrb    r4, [r0, #5]
```

[79 44](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/KzC5t7QF/0)

```
.data:00000000  4479    add     r1, pc
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use [capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/). An example is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from capstone import *

CODE = b"\x44\x79"

md = Cs(CS_ARCH_ARM, CS_MODE_THUMB|CS_MODE_LITTLE_ENDIAN)
for (address, size, mnemonic, op_str) in md.disasm_lite(CODE, 0x1000):
    print("0x%x:\t%s\t%s" %(address, mnemonic, op_str))
```

0x1000: ldrb    r4, [r0, #5]

Comment: will is cause a problem if I change 0x1000 to 0x0000?